# What happens to generated but unsent transactions?

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, ledger-nano-s

I created a transaction in mew with nano s. I generated a transaction, clicked confirm on nano s, but missed the final step of clicking send transaction in the mew screen.  I can't find the transaction anywhere now, not listed in history...will this transaction eventually cancel and have my funds returned to wallet?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction, as far as the blockchain is concerned, never existed. It's like recording a video and then deleting it -- you might as well not have recorded it. There shouldn't be any sign of your funds leaving your account.